# i need to given state and district details in same select box with ngFor angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, ngfor

This is my json value,

```
{
"location": [{
        "state": "state1",
        "cities": [{
                "city1": "city1"
            },
            {
                "city2": "city2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "state": "state2",
        "cities": [{
                "city1": "city1"
            },
            {
                "city2": "city2"
            },
            {
                "city3": "city"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

**sample output in select box:**

**state1** - state name - parent

city1  - city name - child

city2

---

**state2** - state name - parent

city1 - city name - child

city2

city3

```
    <select>
      <option *ngFor="let locations of location">
        {{locations.state}}{{locations.cities.citiname}}
      </option>
   <select>
```

it is not multiselect. it is like grouping by state under cities.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `optgroup` attribute for `select` element.

```
<select>
  <optgroup *ngFor="let location of locations" [label]="location.state">
    <option *ngFor="let city of location.cities">{{Utils.keys(city)[0]}}</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Typescript

```
Utils = {
     keys : Object.keys
}
```

You cannot use directly `Object.keys` because `Object` is a part of `window/global` and `angular` cannot evaluate that expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i will check

Comment: i got it.  i got error "key is not defined"  but i populated my cities value directly.it is solved. again Thanks.